# How long can I stay in Germany after my resident permit expired?

Tags: germany, resident-permit

I have a resident permit (Aufenthalstitel) from Germany. The resident permit is going to expire soon, say on 1 April. I do not intend to extend my stay in Germany. Should I leave before 1 April (the expiry date)? If not, how long can I stay in Germany after 1 April?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I leave before 1 April (the expiry date)? If not, how long can I stay in Germany after 1 April?

You should leave while the residence permit is still valid.

This especially true if you intend to transit through another Schengen Country and your citizenship normaly requires a Schengen Visa to enter the Schengen Area.

An exact amount of days after the residence permit expires and an overstay is tolerated is not defined.

> [§ 50 Obligation to leave the federal territory - Residence Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1042)
> (1) Foreigners are required to leave the federal territory if they do not or no longer possess the necessary residence title and no right of residence exists or no longer exists under the EEC/Turkey Association Agreement.
>
> (2) Such foreigners must leave the federal territory **without delay** or, if a period has been allowed for departure, by the end of this period.
> ...